# Issue on executing Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand on azure automation

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation

Trying to run custom script on azure vm through azure automation run-books using Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand. But getting below exception

> InvokeAzureRmVMRunCommand begin processing with ParameterSet
>   'DefaultParameter'. using account id
>   'qwerqe-xxxxx-4fde-9f1a-3d4d92ed055c'...
>   System.Management.Automation.Host.HostException: A command that
>   prompts the user failed because the host program or the  command type
>   does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to request
>   confirmation with the following  message: A command that prompts the
>   user failed because the host program or the command type does not
>   support user  interaction. The host was attempting to request
>   confirmation with the following message: Are you sure you want to 
>   perform this action? Performing the operation "Invoke" on target
>   "VM_Name".

Script:

```
# Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "

 $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

  $login =  Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 


$rgname = 'RG-Name'
$vmname = 'VM-Name'
$localmachineScript = 'PowerShell script file on your local machine like script-test.ps1'
wget "https://automationbackupstorage.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/$localmachineScript" -outfile $localmachineScript 
Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Name $vmname -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath $localmachineScript -Parameter @{"arg1" = "var1";"arg2" = "var2"} -Debug
```

Comment: Please show your complete script in the question, otherwise we could not test for you.

Comment: @JoyWang update with the script

Comment: Does the script work in local?

Comment: not tested in local.. just started with azure automation for few use cases...

Comment: Thanks for u r effort to replicate and trying … and its really helped me to solve the issue.

Comment: @JoyWang: The execution script performs copy of files from one vm to another in azure which are in same subnet. When we execute the below script directly from PS it works .. but with automation it executes successfully but copy of files are not happening... any suggestion would be helpful .

Copy-Item -Path C:\folder\sample.txt -Destination \\VmHostname\C$\folder -Force

Comment: For the different issue, I recommend you to ask it in a new post, it will be clear to others.

Comment: @JoyWang: as suggested created new post https://stackoverflow.com/q/62260399/1014275

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I can reproduce your issue on my side.

[image]

The issue was caused by the `-Debug`, it will promote you to confirm the action, but in Azure Runbook, it does not support the user interaction, so we could not use it in runbook. If you want to get the output, you could use something like `Write-Output`.

[image]

Also, I don't think `wget "https://automationbackupstorage.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/$localmachineScript" -outfile $localmachineScript` will work in runbook, if you want to download the blob in the storage to the runbook, your option is to use `Get-AzStorageBlobContent` to download the blob to the temp folder(`$env:temp`) of runbook.

**Note**: In your script, you use the old `AzureRM` module commands, it was deprecated and will not be updated, in my sample, I use the new [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-3.8.0) commands, I recommend you to also use this.

To fix the issue and run your command correctly, please follow the steps below.

1. Navigate to the automation account in the portal -> `Modules`, make sure you have installed the `Az.Accounts`, `Az.Storage`, `Az.Compute` moudles, if not, go to the `Browse Gallery` -> search for the module name and install.

   [image]
2. In the powershell runbook, use the sample like below, it works for me. If your script needs some parameters, just pass them.

   ```
   $connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
   $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

   $login =  Connect-AzAccount `
           -ServicePrincipal `
           -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
           -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
           -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 

   $localmachineScript = "testrun.ps1"
   $context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "<StorageAccountName>" -StorageAccountKey "<StorageAccountKey>"
   Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Container "<container-name>" -Blob $localmachineScript -Context $context -Destination $env:temp -Force

   $result = Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName <group-name> -VMName <vm-name> -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath "$env:temp\$localmachineScript"
   Write-Output "The result:" $result.Value[0].Message
   ```

[image]